# Is working with the Session thread-safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, thread-safety

Consider a user making multiple requests at the same time, do I have to lock all code that works with the Session?

If for example I have the following scenario, where in one tab of his browser the user opens a page and in the second he logs out.

Request 1:

```
if(Session["user"] != null)
    lblName.Text = Session["user"].Name;
```

Request 2:

```
if(logout)
   Session["user"] = null;
```

Is it possible that Request 1 throws a NullPointerException when accessing the Name property? Do i need to lock the code in Request 1, to make sure user still exists after checking for null? Or does ASP.NET deal with this automatically somehow?

Comment: I would be passing a reference, right? What if Request2 calls Session["user"].Dispose()? Would that affect the user I got out of the Session in Request1?

Comment: Yes you could be using a disposed object in that case.

Comment: Peter Ruderman's answer says it could not be null in Request 1. Two opinions - what's correct?

Comment: @atticae: It depends on whether you're using in-memory or SQL-based session state.  In any case, you should assume that the object could be shared between multiple threads and synchronize access appropriately.

Comment: @Darryl Braaten: There is no race condition in Request 1 because ASP.NET uses reader and writer locks on Session. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx

Comment: @Jacob thanks for the link,  I was incorrect.  Though it is still possible to get a race on disposing an object in the session.

Comment: @Darryl: you are right: calling a method on an object read from session can cause side effects on that object, despite not holding the write lock.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As always, the answer depends on what you mean by "safety."  In ASP .NET, each request gets exclusive access to its session state.  This means that you don't have to worry about synchronizing access within the scope of a single request.  If Session["user"] is non-null, then it will be non-null for the entire duration of the current request.  In your example, request 1 will never throw a null reference exception.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know. That contradicts what Darryl Braaten wrote in the comments above, though. So who is right? :)

Comment: This is not entirely correct - in the default InProc mode, ASP.NET does not make a copy of session state; it uses reader and writer locks to prevent non-repeatable reads. This means that Request 2 will block until Request 1 has finished, because Request 1 holds the reader lock on this session. The effect is the same, but the mechanism is quite different.

Comment: Yes, the picture is quite a bit more complicated than I described above, but the key point is that you don't have to synchronize access. Depending on whether the request is marked as requiring session state, you'll get either exclusive access or an exclusive copy.

Answer (score 16):

Two requests to an ASP.NET application for the same same session, where the handlers do not use the [`IReadOnlySessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) marker interface or have the [`EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx) turned on for your pages, will be serialized by the ASP.NET runtime to guarantee consistency of the state. So if you have two pages that are able to write to the session state, they will be accessed serially no matter what the client does on their side.

It's up to your application code to signal to ASP.NET with the afforementioned techniques whether or not a page/handler is going to write to the session state. If you do not, all requests will be serialized and the performance of your web application will suffer.

Comment: Ok wow, I never thought Session was such a complex topic. I'm learning a lot here, thanks guys.

Comment: Is this true in ASP.Net Core too? I am seeing the DistributedSession implementation (which is instantiating by default) and there are no traces of any serialization technique, like locks...

Comment: @g.pickardou Does this Threat Safety on Asp.net is still applied on ASP.NET Core. ? I have concurrency problems reading and writing back to a same key on the session from different concurrent requests on the same browser

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET, the [Session module uses a pair of reader/writer locks per session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx), so Request 1 will have consistent reads, and Request 2 will block until Request 1 completes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Session is thread-safe.

There's no need to **lock** anything. However, the need to **check** the values never cease to be essential.

**Update**

Check @Peter Ruderman's answer :)

I will have the decency of not copying it :)

Comment: I guess my question title is wrong, should probably be something like "Is working with Session thread-safe"

Comment: You should then update your question, because that will change the answer.

Comment: Ok, did now. I still dont think the title is perfect, but better than before. ;)

Comment: What do we need to check then?