# Is ASP.NET Core Session implementation thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, session, asp.net-core, concurrency, httpcontext

I know that [there is an analogous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7013055/1157814) but that is about ASP.NET and not about ASP.NET Core. The answers are 7-9 years old, and mixing there talking about ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core may not be a good idea.

**What I mean thread safe in this case:**

Is it safe to use the read write methods (like `Set(...)`) of the `Session` (accessed via `HttpContext`, which accessed via an injected `IHttpContextAccessor`) in multiple requests belonging to the same session?

The obvious answer would be yes, because if it would not be safe, then all developers should make their session accessing code thread safe...

I took a look of the [`DistributedSession` source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v3.0.0-preview5-19227-01/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSession.cs) which seems to be the default (my session in the debugger which accessed as described above is an instance of `DistributedSession`) and no traces of any serialization or other techniques, like locks... even the private `_store` member is a pure `Dictionary`...

How could be this thread safe for concurrent modification usage? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DistributedSession` is created by [`DistributedSessionStore`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSessionStore.cs) which is [registered as a transient dependency](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Middleware/Session/src/SessionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs). That means that the `DistributedSessionStore` itself is implicitly safe because it isn’t actually shared between requests.

The session uses a dictionary as the underlying data source which is also local to the `DistributedSession` object. When the session is initialized, the session initializes the `_store` dictionary lazily when the session is being accessed, by deserializing the stored data from the cache. [That looks like this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSession.cs#L174-L178):

```
var data = _cache.Get(_sessionKey);
if (data != null)
{
    Deserialize(new MemoryStream(data));
}
```

So the access to `_cache` here is a single operation. The same applies when [writing to the cache](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSession.cs#L271-L275).

As for `IDistributedCache` implementations, you can usually expect them to be thread-safe to allow parallel access. The `MemoryCache` for example uses [a concurrent collection as the backing store](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/v2.2.5/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L21).

What all this means for concurrent requests is basically that you should not expect one request to directly impact the session of the other request. Sessions are usually only deserialized once so updates that happen during the request (by other requests) will not appear.

Comment: Many thanks. Meanwhile I've also did some research. Do I understand correctly, if I access to the session as I described, then every request will have a very separate exclusive session instance.  The concurrent requests in the same session will not interfere, with the (zero) price of they will not see each others writes instantly. The content of the exclusive instance's private store dictionary will be written to a common store _after_ that session instance is done its all work.

Comment: Yes, every request has its own `DistributedSession` instance that has its own snapshot of the session state at a certain time. It’s only at the end of a request that the session is committed which results in it being written back to the (shared) cache.

Comment: Hey this will be a problem if i make concurrent requests from the same browser that use the same key data in the shared cache, session will be the same but the snapshot of the session state results different if i need to write back to the cache the same key with new data